# Java generics - passing a collection of subtype to a method requiring a collection of base type

Tags: java, generics

How to do this in Java - passing a collection of subtype to a method requiring a collection of base type?

The example below gives:

```
The method foo(Map<String,List>) is not applicable for the arguments (Map<String,MyList>)
```

I can implement by creating a class hierarchy for the typed collections - but is it possible otherwise?

```
public void testStackOverflow() {

    class MyList extends AbstractList {
        public Object get(int index) {
            return null;
        }
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }           
    };

    Map <String, List>   baseColl = null;
    Map <String, MyList> subColl  = null;

    foo (subColl);              
}

private void foo (Map <String, List> in) {      
}
```

EDIT: Turns out from the answers that this requires "bounded wildcard" so adding this text for searchability

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change `foo` to:

```
private void foo(Map <String, ? extends List> in) {
}
```

That will restrict what you can do within `foo`, but that's reasonable. You know that any value you fetch from the map will be a list, but you don't know what kind of value is valid to put into the map.

Answer (score 2):

as jon s says:

```
private void foo (Map <String, ? extends List> in { ... }
```

will fix the errors. you will still have warnings though. take a look the get-put principle at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07018.html

Comment: java generics are not easy, "java generics and collections" (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754/) is very helpful.