# Java Collections: Pass collection of children as collection of parents

Tags: java, generics, collections

Say I have an interface and some classes:

```
public interface IPanel<ComponentType extends Component> {
   public void addComponents(Set<ComponentType> components);
   public ComponentType create();
}

public class Button extends Component { }

public class LocalizedButton extends Button { }

public class ButtonsPanel implements IPanel<Button> {
    public void addComponents(Set<Button> components) { ... /* uses create() */ ; }
    public Button create() { return new Button(); }
}

public class LocalizedButtonsPanel extends ButtonsPanel {
    public Button create() { return new LocalizedButton(); }
}
```

Then I have a set of LocalizedButtons and when I call

```
final LocalizedButtonsPanel localizedButtonsPanel = new LocalizedButtonsPanel();
final Set<LocalizedButton> localizedButtonsSet = new LinkedHashSet<LocalizedButton>();
localizedButtonsPanel.addComponents(localizedButtonsSet);
```

I get that this method is not applicable for this arguments.
If I try to overload this method as `addComponents(Set<LocalizedButton> buttons)` in `LocalizedButtonsPanel`, I get type erasure, of course.

May be some pattern is missed or the trick exists to deal with this architecture to implement correct adding the set of LocalizedButtons?

---

I've got the answer and I want to make my example more concrete - I have some validators in my implementation, so I need the collection type to be also stored as generic, that is simplified code I've got using the answer:

```
public interface IPanel<ComponentType extends Component, CollectionType extends Collection<? extends Component>> extends Validated<CollectionType> {
   public void addComponents(CollectionType components);
   public ComponentType create();
}

public class Button extends Component { }

public class LocalizedButton extends Button { }

public class ButtonsPanel implements IPanel<Button, Set<? extends Button>> {
    public void addComponents(Set<? extends Button> components) { ... /* uses create() */ ; }
    public Button create() { return new Button(); }
}

public class LocalizedButtonsPanel extends ButtonsPanel {
    public Button create() { return new LocalizedButton(); }
}
```

And in this case, it works

Comment: there is (may be) a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298305/, but the answer there breaks interfaces I have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the addComponents() signature to

```
public void addComponents(Set<? extends Button> components)
```

so that the methods accepts sets of subclasses of Button.
This way, you can pass a `Set<LocalizedButton>` as an argument, because `LocalizedButton` extends `Button` and therefore matches the parameter Type of `Set<? extends Button>`.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. My structure was a little bit more complicated (I'll describe in the question), but I've corrected my generics to fit your advise and it really fits :).

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
public class ButtonsPanel implements IPanel<Button> {
    public void addComponents(Set<Button> components) { ... /* uses create() */ ; }
    public Button create() { return new Button(); }
}
```

Should be

```
public class ButtonsPanel implements IPanel<Button> {
    public void addComponents(Set<? extends Button> components) { ... /* uses create() */ ; }
    public Button create() { return new Button(); }
}
```

The list is created only for the type of button not for Object that extend that type.

Comment: this: `public class ButtonsPanel implements IPanel<? extends Button>`

will not work, because wildcards are not supported in `implements` section, and if I specify

this: `public class GenericButtonsPanel<ButtonType extends Button> implements IPanel<ButtonType>`

then `LocalizedButtonsPanel extends GenericButtonsPanel<LocalizedButton>` in this case will not be the child of `ButtonsPanel` that `extends GenericButtonsPanel<Button>` (and I need constructors without generics)

Answer (score 0):

Parameterised types are not covariant in Java.  This is good, otherwise you would be able to add a Dog to a List<Cat> that had been upcast to List<Animal>.  You can add covariance at the usage site, e.g., List<? extends Animal> can be assigned a List<Cat> and you can't call its add method.